# Running two python scripts sequentially

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I've two scripts for drowsiness and alcohol detection, **codefinal.py** and **example.py**

I want to run these 2 .py files on terminal in Raspberry Pi 3. However, for my drowsiness detection code codefinal.py, I need to manually enter the cv environment using **workon cv** command line.

How do I get these 2 codes to run sequentially, first example.py and then codefinal.py without entering the workon command line?

Comment: Create a shell script that runs `example.py` first then `codefinal.py`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do it, no guarantee it is the best way to but if you want to keep both scripts separate:

Make a Third script:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

def sequential_main():
    process = Popen("cmd.exe", shell=False, universal_newlines=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    commands = '''
    python example.py
    python codefinal.py *ARG* *ARG*\n
    '''
    out, err = process.communicate(commands)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sequential_main():
```

I am using cmd.exe to execute the scripts sequentially , you might have a different way on Raspberry Pi 3 terminal. Note that while calling a script on terminal you can add arguments to your script call which you can access in **codefinal.py** as argv[1], argv[2] ... Use as many as you need for your manual inputs.
If you need to manually input them in your new script, just call the `input()` function and store your inputs as `string`: **Input1**, **Input2**, ... and use this:

```
commands = '''
        python example.py
        python codefinal.py {} {}\n
        '''.format(Input1, Input2)
```